How could I add Gothic windows to this castle model?
I made this castle model and would like to add Gothic windows to it, however, modeling it directly onto the mesh is a no option because it is a bit asymmetrical (especially the base mesh that connects all the towers, which are separate meshes) and has uneven topology (all quads though) and I want the windows to be more or less equal sized. I thought about adding it as a separate mesh with an array modifier, but then my problem is that the walls would block out the window glasses. How could I get around this problem?
Here is the model:


can't you just remove some of the wall faces to make the windows? If not, I don't see how you could do

Never mind, I just retopologized the base. I kept the towers because they are very regular, so the windows will be easy to model onto them, but the base mesh had to go.
